# Adding custom month buttons to FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'd like to be able to add a row of buttons across the header of the calendar that displays the months of the year, and when clicked, takes you to that month in month view.

I've tried and failed to to add this using views. In this example I want the calendar to skip to January:

```
views: {
    january: {
            type: 'month',
            duration: { months: 1 },
            start  : '2016-01-01',
            end: '2016-01-31',
            buttonText: 'January'
            }
        },
```

Anyone any ideas? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could this be helpful? http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/

Comment: I suggest making 12 buttons yourself and call `.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date)` inside those functions. Creating views is an option too, it's just a little more work. I can help you creating 12 buttons that do exactly what you want ;)

Comment: Tohveli - thats what I was trying to use but I couldn't work out, using views, how to create a month that started on a certain day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

This will add button to the right when the page loads. write this inside ready function.

```
$('.fc-right').find('.fc-button-group').after("<input type='button' value='january' onclick='gotoJan();'");
```

Then inside the function.

```
 function gotoJan() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', '2014-01-01');
 }
```